trying to make a Iframe box height larger on a webpage
I am chiropractor and run a business here
okisporstanspinal.com
you can see that when browsing on a mobile device the height of the Iframe that hosts the external booking service is very small and hard to navigate.
See here for example
https://okisportsandspinal.com/asiaphysio/
I don't think the fault lies in the code from the cloud based software but rather a theme with my website.
I am hoping I can increase the size of the embedded Iframe with some custom CSS
Can anybody help me? It's driving me crazy

You can add a min-height for a mobile with a media query, like so:
@media (max-width: 600px){
  iframe {
    min-height: 1000px !important;
 }
}

This will increase it with 1000 pixels under 600 pixels width of the screen-size, so it will be easier to navigate.
Important:
Make sure you add this to the end of your stylesheet (style.css file).

Dude !! You bloody legend :) I tied that and it worked perfectly !

@BrentVerco :-) I'm glad it worked. You may consider marking it as the chosen answer if it really helped you.
